# Visual Studio: Web Performance Test with WebAPI pos bodies for complex types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, performance-testing

I've built a WebAPI endpoint that looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public QueryResultSet PostFetchResults(QueryRequest request)
{
    // Does some stuff
}
```

I have a Web Performance Test (the VS framework), and want to know how to create the proper post request for this endpoint. When I create a Form Post Field I'm obviously forced to add a parameter name; however, as I understand it WebAPI simply applies a media-formatter to the post body to acquire the allowed FromBody parameter.

Which option should I be choosing to make this work for me? Is this something I'll have to code up?

Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up needing to code my own plug-in for this. Thankfully, Microsoft already did my work for me: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458708.aspx

This will only work for web requests, but presumably that's all you would need for interacting with WebAPI.